# textfield validation before submitting request to server

Tags: java, android, json, forms, validation

I'm working on a registration form for an android app and I'm trying to use the setError feature to validate the textfields when the user clicks the register button. It is running through the checks but is still submitting the form to my server for registration. I want all the fields to be valid before submitting the request to register the user. I have been searching for a solution for hours but just can't tell what I'm doing wrong.  Please help!

```
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String first_name = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
            String last_name = inputLastName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String dob = displaytxt.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(first_name, last_name, email, dob, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if(inputFirstName.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                {
                    inputFirstName.setError("First name required!");
                }
                if (inputLastName.getText().toString().length() < 0)
                {
                    inputLastName.setError("Last name required!");
                }
                if (inputEmail.getText().toString().length() == 0)
                {
                    inputEmail.setError( "Valid email address required!" );
                }
                if (inputPassword.getText().toString().length() < 8)
                {
                    inputPassword.setError( "Password required! (Minimum of 8 characters." );
                }
                if (!inputPassword2.getText().toString().equals(inputPassword.getText().toString()))
                {
                    inputPassword.setError( "Passwords do not match! (Minimum of 8 characters.");
                    inputPassword2.setError("Passwords do not match! (Minimum of 8 characters.");
                }
                if (!checkBoxTerms.isChecked());
                {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("oops!");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("You must agree to the terms & conditions.");
                    alertDialog.setButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    //dismiss the dialog
                                }
                            });

                    alertDialog.show();
                }
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRST_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_LAST_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json_user.getString(KEY_DOB), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in registration! Please check the information entered.");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just debug your code, I think you have getting one value wrong and its going in if part. That's why its occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To aggregate all errors and only after return from  `onClick` use error flag, like:

```
boolean isError = false; 

 if(inputFirstName.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
            {
                inputFirstName.setError("First name required!");
                isError = true;
            }
            if (inputLastName.getText().toString().length() < 0)
            {
                inputLastName.setError("Last name required!");
                isError = true;
            }
            if (inputEmail.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            {
                inputEmail.setError( "Valid email address required!" );
                isError = true;
            }
            if (inputPassword.getText().toString().length() < 8)
            {
                inputPassword.setError( "Password required! (Minimum of 8 characters." );
                isError = true;
            }
            if (!inputPassword2.getText().toString().equals(inputPassword.getText().toString()))
            {
                inputPassword.setError( "Passwords do not match! (Minimum of 8 characters.");

                inputPassword2.setError("Passwords do not match! (Minimum of 8 characters.");
                 isError = true;
            }

   if(isError){
       return;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The method you gave does aggregate all the errors on the form so I appreciate your help with that. However the form can still be submitted if the first, last, email is filled in. Seems to pass the info to my database anyways. I think it might an issue with my DatabaseHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working perfect for me

```
buttonClicked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (lastName.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            lastName.setError("Enter LastName");
                        }else{
                            //call your intent
                        }

                    } 
            });

            lastName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    lastName.setError(null);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    lastName.setError(null);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and import this class here
[Android Form Validation Class](https://github.com/cokeby190/FormValidation)

This can help you to validate the Form fields, just need to follow the instructions. (: